# Multiple validation error issue while saving a model in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having an issue while saving a user object in the database. I have two fields in the model (email and password) which are not allowed to be null in the database itself. Plus I have added validation in the model like

```
  validates_presence_of :email, :message => "must be provided"
  validates_presence_of :password, :message => "must be provided"
```

Now when I try to save the model from the create method of the controller, it invalidates the data and renders the new action again. However I have multiple error messages for each field

```
Email can't be blank
Email must be provided
Password can't be blank
Password must be provided
```

I don't need multiple error messages for the same one. How can I eliminate this?

Comment: You have two lots of validation happening by the looks of it.  Can you post your model code?  Does your model inherit directly from `ActiveRecord::Base` or have you interjected a class between your model class and it?  If so, do you have validations in the intermediate class.  Basically, we need some more to go on. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are validating in two different places. You have to figure it out the places...

If you are doing two different validation for a field and want to display one error message on a field at a time, you can do the following,

```
validates_presence_of   :email, :message => "must be provided"
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => "must be unique", 
     :if => lambda { |a| a.errors.on(:email).blank? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are rendering errors twice. Check all your views, they can also be inherited.

Comment: Hmm, the errors are different though.  It looks more like there are two sets of validations going on - rendering again in Rails won't cause a re-validation anyway.